# Один и тот же обработчик события несколько раз на элементе. Будут ли проблемы?

Tags: javascript, события

Добрый день! У меня есть функция, которая вешает на элемент обработчик `div.addEventListener("click", move)`. В процессе работы приложения эта функция может запускаться неограниченное кол-во раз (зависит от действий пользователя). Этот обработчик я ни где не снимаю.

Я по тестировал немного, проблем не возникает. Но все же, могу ли возникнуть проблемы связанные с этим?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

> Если зарегистрировано несколько одинаковых `EventListener`-ов на одном `EventTarget` с одинаковыми параметрами, **дублирующиеся слушатели игнорируются**. Они не позволяют `EventListener`-у быть вызванным дважды, и так как одинаковые слушатели игнорируются, не требуется удалять их вручную с помощью метода `removeEventListener`.

То есть список разрастается потихоньку, что, конечно,  не очень то хорошо, но события повторно не вызываются.

Comment: Понял, благодарю!